# DIY Playback Controlling Audio Receiver

Tags: audio, bluetooth, controls, playback

How do those car HiFis with full playback control (including access to the playlist) on your phone work exactly.

First I just wanted to build a DIY Bluetooth receiver that could display the now playing track on a screen, then I realized that some car infotainment systems even let you browse your playlists on your phone. I was trying to look after how this works exactly, but unfortunately found not a single useful documentation on it (probably used wrong keywords). Not even one on the original idea as to display the current track.
I was trying to look after some programmable A2DP modules, but I still have no idea if they can pass the required information over to, say, an Arduino or else.
Soooo... I don't want to control the HiFi with my phone but rather control my phone with the HiFi.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.